# Wordpress database sync in team development environment

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, git

Right now I'm working on a wordpress web-site that synchronize its codebase using GIT. It works well for files but when it comes to a database nightmare starts to happen. We have several servers, one for QA, another for marketing and a final one for production. All of these servers have their own database setup. If I work on one of the servers and modify smth. in a database through wp-admin and someone else do smth else on another server, we need to manually merge all of our database changes.
So the question is: Is there a way to work from the same database on different web-site instances? If I make some change to the db, I want these change to be reflected on all of the servers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to all be working from the same database. I haven't found anything that handles a merge very well. The closest I got was [WP-Stagecoach](https://wpstagecoach.com/) though that doesn't quite cover it. I've been told that [Datahawk](https://datahawk.io/) will do it but it's still in development.

This may help though - I work with another developer, we both work locally on our computers using MAMP. We use one database which is hosted by our local server. Git is then used to download files between our local setups. So there's no need for merging the database as that seems to be the biggest headache.